# How to pass db object to mysqli_query in PHP class method

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

i'm trying to make a Mysql query in a class method, and trying to pass db object to mysql_query function.

But it gives this error: 
**mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in...**

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $db_host = DB_HOST;
    private $db_user = DB_USER;
    private $db_pass = DB_PASS;
    private $db_name = DB_NAME;
    public $link;
    public $error;

    // Constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
    private function connect()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
        if (!$this->link) {
            $this->error = "Database'e baglanilamiyor: " . $this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
        $this->link->query($this->link, "SET NAMES UTF8");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass db object to an in class query...
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think your connect function needs to return the connection object. Try that and see if that works.

Comment: try $this->link->query("SET NAMES UTF8", $this->link);

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php   in object mode, you do NOT pass in the connection handle. That's only necessary in procedural mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing queries with with the mysqli object is done this way:

```
$mysqli_instance->query('select/update/...');
```

In your case the mysqli_instance is `$this->link` and the query - `"SET NAMES UTF8"`. Just replace both in the pattern above:

```
$this->link->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a database object you need to use singleton to be able to connect once to that database. 
You need to create an instance of the database and verify that it is connected before releasing the connection.

Then when you do your query, it will look something like this.

```
   public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
     */
    private function __clone() { }

    /* Return a connection */
    public function getConnection()
    {
        return $this->_connection;
    }
```

Then to access this database and do query, you need to do something like this.

```
   /** @var Database $connection */
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $connection = $db->getConnection();

  /** You need to create your query then use this kind kind of statement assuming you have already done the rest */
  $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
```